# NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file - UNIT TEST Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test this piece of code:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LeMigrationService {

    private final MigrationServiceClient migrationServiceClient;

    public FileUploadRs process(MultipartFile file) {

        List<String> listOfCifs = null;
        try {
            listOfCifs = ExcelUtil.collectColumnByIndex(file, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to load excel file content " + e);
        }

        return migrationServiceClient.process(listOfCifs);
    }
}
```

The static method:

```
public class ExcelUtil {

    public static List<String> collectColumnByIndex(MultipartFile file, int index) throws Exception {
        List<String> listOfCifs = new ArrayList<>();

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row row : sheet) {

            Cell cell = row.getCell(index);
            int cellLength = cell.getStringCellValue().length();

            if (cellLength < 9) {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9 - cellLength; i++) {
                    str.append("0");
                }
                str.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                listOfCifs.add(str.toString());
            }
            if (cellLength > 9) {
                break;
            }
            if(cellLength == 9) {
                listOfCifs.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }

        return listOfCifs;
    }

}
```

And finally my unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LeMigrationServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void processFile_FileContentIsOk() throws Exception{

        //arrange
        final MockMultipartFile fakeFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "file.xls", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "0123456789".getBytes());

        //act
        final List<String> actual = ExcelUtil.collectColumnByIndex(fakeFile, 0);

        final List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.set(0, "0123456789");

        //assert
        assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
    }

}
```

When I run the test, I get the error when it calls the static method "collectColumnByIndex". Apparently I do not create well the object "Workbook" inside the method "collectColumnByIndex". Do you have any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: You are reading an `xls` file using a `xlsx` based java implementation. XLS != XLSX. Use a different workbook to open the correct file or switch the file to a correct one,

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you're right. Thanks a lot !